# R add json string with polygons to leaflet

Tags: json, r, leaflet, geospatial, geos

I would like to intergrate a couple of polygons into my leaflet map. These polygons are written in WKT. By using the package `wellknown` i convert them to a `geosjon` format

```
InstallCandidates <-c("jsonlite","leaflet","wellknown","rgdal","sp")
toInstall<-InstallCandidates[!InstallCandidates %in% library()$results[,1]]
if(length(toInstall) !=0){install.packages(toInstall,repos="http://cran.r-project.org")}
lapply(InstallCandidates,library,character.only=TRUE)
rm("InstallCandidates","toInstall")

url<- "https://kaart.amsterdam.nl/datasets/datasets-item/t/cora-geplande-wegwerkzaamheden/export/json"
werkzaamheden <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(url))
```

The var `linestring` is one WKT object in this url.

```
linestring<- "LINESTRING (4.9473233812748 52.304767613036, 4.9473234970894 52.304755910603, 4.947323612904 52.30474420817, 4.9473350439563 52.304746591253, 4.9473310174218 52.304767641433, 4.9473119270542 52.304767570438)"
locatie<- wkt2geojson(linestring, feature = FALSE)
class(locatie)
```

Is tried to plot this linestring in a `leaflet` object by doing this:

```
leaflet(data = locatie) %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addGeoJSON(geojson =locatie,  color = "red",fill = "red")
```

But i dont see the linestring, could anyone help me pleas?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a bug in `addGeoJSON()`.  I have submitted here https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/368.

Comment: Thank you very much @timelyportfolio!